# Firebase v9 uploading image shows only 9 bytes

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

im using react native and firebase (v9) to upload image to firebase. in the firebase storage, the file was uploaded, but the size is only 9 bytes so it's not opening properly. I'm not sure how to fix this :S

```
const uploadFiles = (file, name, storeKey) => {
    if(!file){
        console.log('no file exists')
        return;
    }
    const exe = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.'));
    const fileName = name + exe;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/files/${fileName}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', null,
        (error) => {
            alert(error);
        },
        () => {
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
            .then((URL) => {
                setDoc(doc(db, 'Store', storeKey, 'coffeeDB', name), {postImage: URL}, {merge: true});
                console.log('url registered')
            });
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're calling `file.substring(...)`, it seems that `file` is a file name. You can't upload a file by just passing its name, as that'd be a security risk. Instead you'll need to pass a `Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadbytes) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#web-version-9_1), typically by passing the `File` reference from which you got the file name.

Comment: thank u! now i have to working blob :D

Answer (score 1):

I had a strange issue with angular 14 and angular fire 7 using tinymce. Uploading the image and selecting the file would upload correctly to firebase, but dragging and dropping the same image file into tinymce would result in the file being uploaded to firebase as a 9 byte octet-stream file like you were seeing. Inspecting the blobInfo it all appeared correctly, had the filename, correct size, image/png as contentType but the AngularFireStorage.upload method was just ignoring the metadata. Ended up getting it working using the .base64 method on the blobInfo and sending it to firebase using the .putString method against the generated ref.

```
    images_upload_handler: (blobInfo:any) => {
  const file: any = blobInfo.base64();
  const filePath = `${this.currentTemplateItemId}-${blobInfo.blob().name}`;
  const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
  const metadata = { contentType: blobInfo.blob().type };
  const task = ref.putString(file, "base64", metadata);
  const promise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    task
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() =>
          ref
            .getDownloadURL()
            .pipe(last())
            .subscribe((url) => {
              resolve(url);
            })
        )
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
      }, error => {
        reject('Error uploading image. Please ensure the file is less than 150kb');
      });
  });
```

Just using this.storage.upload(filePath, blobInfo.blob(), metadata) (which should do the same thing but send the blob instead wasn't working).
Slightly different cause to what you were seeing but leaving this here for ideas in case others are also getting issues with image uploads to firebase ending up with 9 byte files.